# How to access `this` value within the object

Tags: javascript

In below code I can access `wrapper` like this: `tutorial.screen1.wrapper`

```
var tutorial = {
  screen1: {
    text: '<div class="text">Click this to continue</div>',
    wrapper: '<div class="tutorial tutorial-screen-1">' + this.text + '</div>'
  }
```

Because `this.text` cannot be accessed, `tutorial.screen1.wrapper` throws error.

How to make this `this.text` work with in the object?

Comment: Im not 100% sure, but I think he is meaning `this.text` as `tutorial.screen1.text`. ie he wants to use the value of `tutorial.screen1.text` in `tutorial.screen1.wrapper`, to get something like `wrapper: '<div class="tutorial tutorial-screen-1">' + '<div class="text">Click this to continue</div>' + '</div>'`

Comment: @Krusader that won't work, since you are referencing the tutorial object before it is defined

Comment: In your example, `this` refers to `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this by creating `wrapper` as function

```js
var tutorial = {
  screen1: {
    text: '<div class="text">Click this to continue</div>',
    wrapper: function() {
      return '<div class="tutorial tutorial-screen-1">' + this.text + '</div>'

    }
  }
}
console.log(tutorial.screen1.wrapper())
```